# How to convert an array of PIL images into a base64-formatted PDF string?

Tags: python, base64, python-imaging-library, odoo-10

This function below accepts a JSON string of a bunch of base64-encoded images inside. I need this thing to return a base64-encoded PDF, and it does but it would only give me one page, the first image inside the JSON string... I have this code:

```
import json
import base64
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np
import cv2

class ImageStuff(models.TransientModel):
   _name = 'image.camera_scan'
   _description = 'Do stuff with your images'

    @api.model
    def generate_pdf_from_b64(self, b64_arr_str):
       b64_arr = json.loads(b64_arr_str)
       pil_arr, count, pil0 = [], 0, False
       for blob in b64_arr:
           b64 = blob['b64'].split(',')[1]
           pil = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(b64)))
           if count > 0: pil_arr.append(pil)
           else: pil0 = pil
           count += 1

       in_mem_file = BytesIO()

       pil0.save(in_mem_file, format="PDF", resolution=100.0, 
                 save_all=True, append_images=pil_arr) 
                 # I think it's that line above that doesn't work

       in_mem_file.seek(0)
       img_bytes = in_mem_file.read()
       base64_encoded_result_bytes = base64.b64encode(img_bytes)
       b64_str = base64_encoded_result_bytes.decode('ascii')

       return b64_str
```

I'm a bit of a newbie with python (I'm sure you can see that in the code). But as much as possible I would like to avoid using anymore modules that didn't come with python 2.7.

I'm using Odoo 10.0 API with this thing, and I can't use pip, so it's kind of a pain importing new modules. Although, if you think there really is no way that I can do it with using only PIL, I will still greatly welcome the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine, it just turns out that odoo 10's PIL module was very outdated, just needed to upgrade it